# What's the difference between curl -v vs curl -I

Tags: curl

What's the difference between `curl -v` and `curl -I`?

I can see `-v` is verbose and `-I` is headers. Anything specific though?

Answer (score 3):

[-I](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-I) (uppercase letter i) means "no body" in curl speak, which for HTTP means sending a `HEAD` request. Such a request doesn't get response body. It also enables "show response headers".

[-v](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) (lower case letter v) means "verbose mode please" and will make curl show its request, the response headers and additional informational details about the transfer performed.

### Additionally

You can get even more information with [--trace](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace) or [--trace-ascii](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii) or you can select to get to see the response headers as part of the regular output if you use [-i](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-i) (lower case letter i).